# Is Plasma 5.7 coming Ubuntu 16.04 at all?

Tags: 16.04, plasma, plasma-5

It seems the PPA hasn't been updated though Plasma 5.7 has been out for a significant time now.

I don't want to use KDE Neon (that's a whole distro, and I can't just nuke my files and start over). How do I get Plasma 5.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're on your own until it arrives to `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`. I'm not sure if it will.

Source: http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/plasma-5-7 mentioned it will be available in backports but they don't know when.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that, or is that just a guess?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/plasma-5-7
They mentioned it will be available in backports but they don't know when.

Comment: Great, thanks!  It would improve your answer to include that link as well.